# Fill a drop down menu with serial ports and saving the choosed label and using it later with Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, drop-down-menu, tkinter, pyserial

I'm trying to do a GUI with Tkinter (python 2.7) that finds what serial COM's are in use and then the user can choose one to communicate with, much like Arduino's IDE in "Tools -> Port". I have two main problems: 1º When I insert the COM ports in the drop down menu, no matter which label I choose, always returns the higher COM number one. I've got an idea why but still can't solve it. 2º I don't know how to save the chosen label and use it later.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox 
from serial import *
import serial

def find_ports(): #find all active COM's

    active_ports = []
    for number in range(10):
        try:
            verify = serial.Serial('COM'+str(number))
            active_ports.append((number, verify.portstr))
            verify.close()

        except serial.SerialException:
            pass
    return active_ports

def chooseCom(index): #choose COM by clicking on a label
    choosedPort = portMenu.entrycget(index, "label")
    print choosedPort
    pass

numPorts = find_ports()
root = Tk()

# -------------------------- Main Frames  --------------------------
toolbar = Frame(root)
data = Frame(root)

# -------------------------- Menu --------------------------
menu = Menu()
root.config(menu = menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu, tearoff = 0)
menu.add_cascade(label="Ports", menu = subMenu)

portMenu = Menu(subMenu, tearoff = 0)
for i,item in enumerate(numPorts):
    portMenu.add_command(label=str(item[-1]), command = lambda: chooseCom(i))   

serialPort = someVAr # someVar => Store the choosed label
baudRate = 9600
ser = Serial(serialPort , baudRate, timeout=0, writeTimeout=0) 

subMenu.add_cascade(label="Ports", menu = portMenu)

root.mainloop()
```

For the 1º problem, I think that is the 'i' variable that stays with a high number by the end of the 'for'. The following code works instead of the 'for' loop:

```
portMenu.add_command(label="COM1", command = lambda: chooseCom(0))
portMenu.add_command(label="COM2", command = lambda: chooseCom(1))
```

unfortunately it doesn't work for me because I'll run this in different computers and I can't garantee that the COM ports will be the same.

The second problem is that I want to save the chosen label in some variable (someVar) and use it later to configure my Serial connection in:

```
serialPort = someVAr # someVar => Store the choosed label
baudRate = 9600
ser = Serial(serialPort , baudRate, timeout=0, writeTimeout=0)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use partial instead of lambda (it's only there for backward compatibility).

```
from functools import partial

portMenu.add_command(label=str(item[-1]), command=partial(chooseCom, i))
```

Also, it is good to get in the habit of not using single letters than can look like numbers, i, l, O.

Comment: That worked for printing the right option in the `chooseCom(index)`, thanks, but how can I store this option in a variable and use it later? I can't access the returned value later even if I add a `return choosedPort` in the `chooseCom` function, or there is a way? I want to use this chosen option (by clicking  in the label inside de dropdown menu) to configure my Serial communication, like in the second problem. Thanks for the advice abouy single letters, I find myself lost everytime but still do the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

I would Strongly Suggest that you learn classes before going any further as it eliminates a lot of problems.  Use a data attribute to store it, so it is visible anywhere within the class http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/userdict.html#fileinfo.userdict.init.example

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

class StoreEntry():
    def __init__(self, root):
        """ shows how to store something in a variable, in this case
            something entered in an Entry, and then print the stored
            value some time later, in this case when the Exit Button
            is pressed
        """
        self.root=root
        self.entered="**"  #default=nothing entered
        tk.Label(root, text="Enter Something").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.entry_1 = tk.Entry(root, width=10, bg="lightblue")
        self.entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="W")
        tk.Button(root, text="return text entered", bg="lightgreen",
              command=self.print_entry).grid(row=2, column=0)
        tk.Button(root, text="Exit", bg="orange",
              command=self.exit_this).grid(row=3, column=0)

    def exit_this(self):
        print "last text entered was", self.entered
        self.root.quit()

    def print_entry(self):
        ## store in a data attribute
        self.entered=self.entry_1.get()
        print self.entered

root=tk.Tk()
SE=StoreEntry(root)
root.mainloop()
```